# Не записываются значения в SQLITE через PDO PHP

Tags: php_pdo, sqlite, php

С БД все ок. "SELECT * FROM wallpapers;" работает нормально через то же PDO. Но тут почему-то ничего не происходит.

```
public static function addWallpaper( $wallpaper_name ) {

    $query = 'INSERT INTO wallpapers (name) VALUES (":wallpaper_name");';
    $prepare = self::$_connection->prepare( $query );
    $prepare->bindValue( ":wallpaper_name", $wallpaper_name );
    $prepare->execute();

}
```

Comment: Проблема была в том, что у php не было прав на запись в папку,где лежит БД.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static function addWallpaper( $wallpaper_name ) {

    $query = 'INSERT INTO wallpapers (name) VALUES (:wallpaper_name);';
    $prepare = self::$_connection->prepare( $query );
    $prepare->bindValue( ":wallpaper_name", $wallpaper_name );
    $prepare->execute();

}
```

Comment: Если написать прямо в бд запрос 
       INSERT INTO wallpapers (name) VALUES (somefile.name);
То БД ответит ошибкой: нет колонки somefile.name. По этому я решил поставить кавычки. Пробовал и без, ничего не меняется

Comment: при бинде значения оно автоматом помещается в кавычки если это строка и соответственно плейсхолдер окружать кавычками не надо, у меня данный код работает

Comment: не работает. даже если написать  
    'INSERT INTO wallpapers (name) VALUES ('value.png');' 
то в БД не появляется строка value.png